# svn check out has issue Could not read chunk size

Tags: svn

I am getting below error, it checks out for a while then it throws me an error, SVN 1.6.

Could please let me know what exactly should be the configuration?

```
REPORT of '/svn/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk size: connection was closed by server. (http://hub.svn.com)
```

Answer (score 3):

How are you hosting the Subversion server?  Is it running behind Apache?

Assuming it's running behind Apache, check your Apache server logs.  The error message is telling you that Apache disconnected the connection during your checkout.  The error logs should give you the detail.  It's probably a timeout that got triggered; check directives like `KeepAlive`, `MaxKeepAliveRequests`, `TimeOut`, `KeepAliveTimeOut`, `MaxRequestsPerChild`, `ThreadLimit`, `MaxThreadsPerChild`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a corrupted working copy.

I suggest checking out a brand new copy of the repository to see.

If the new checkout works without an error, patch over any changes from your old working copy and destroy the old one.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772894/updating-from-svn-repository-returns-could-not-read-chunk-size-error) asked a similar question, but there was no conclusive answer. A common theme in the answers seems to involve working copy corruption.

Comment: Even if i try brand new from the server it gets an issue... same... Its related to size of the files.

Comment: Since it is size related, some kind of timeouts sound very likely. See William Leara's comment. Another issue could be that the reading is not the issue but the writing. I have seen weird error messages, just because the harddrive was full.

Answer (score 1):

In my case Kaspersky blocks the connection.
I just turned Kaspersky off and the checkout completes without problems.

Answer (score 0):

try

> [svn cleanup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.cleanup.html)

Comment: No luck... even it does not work for new directory... tried command line... no luck.