# svnsync fails with "Could not read chunk size..." on the same revision each time

Tags: svn, svnsync

When performing an svnsync sync on a package /user/svn_UefiCpuPkg, it fails consistently after copying the properties for revision 12906.

```
Committed revision 12904.
Copied properties for revision 12904.
Committed revision 12905.
Copied properties for revision 12905.
Committed revision 12906.
Copied properties for revision 12906.
Transmitting file data ..............
(etc.)
......svnsync: REPORT of
'http://edk2.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/edk2/branches/UDK2010.SR1/UefiCpuPkg':
Could not read chunk size: connection was closed by proxy server 
(http://edk2.svn.sourceforge.net)
```

Could it be that revision 12907 has an issue and I need to skip past it?  If so, do I need to create a dummy file like '/db/revprop/12/12907'?

This happens with any package under UDK2010.SR1 so I'm assuming all these packages share revisions and that the issue perhaps lies here.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I should also ask - is it possible to mirror a SVN repository ignoring older revisions completely?  It seems a bit crazy to have to download 14000 revisions in order to set up a local repo...

Comment: There are similar questions: Have you tried the following solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772894/updating-from-svn-repository-returns-could-not-read-chunk-size-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882388/svn-check-out-has-issue-could-not-read-chunk-size

Comment: Yes thanks - looked at lots of similar issues.  Ended up implementing the solution from here: http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2010-02/0115.shtml  which works very well.