# Corrupted branch of project in SVN repository

Tags: svn, version-control, branch

I'm having problems with one branch of a project within our SVN repository.

Firstly I should say that I have worked around the problem by creating another repository for the project.

**The Issue**

We have a mid-sized SVN (around 70gb) repository that contains many projects. It was noticed several weeks ago that svn updates and checkouts were failing on one folder within that branch. The error is;

```
 svn: E175002: REPORT of '/PROJECTNAMEREMOVED/!svn/me': Could not read chunk size: connection was closed by server (http://XX.XXX.0.6:9880)
```

This project was branched from the trunk about five months ago. It has been working for four months with no issues - there are only a couple of developers that are currently using this branch. It was important that this branch be merged back into the project's trunk.

I have tried removing the folder and replacing the contents - still errored.
I have also tried importing the project to another location within the repository. Checking out this project also produced the same error at the same file(s).
The folder were it fails has about 100 files and 4 sub folders. I have tried removing certain files, however the error persists.
I have tried to revert back, however the problem folder hasn't been changed for several months - the 'could not read chuck error' still happened no matter how far I reverted.
There are no reported errors on the repository and I have been unable to find a revision that has caused the issue on this branch.

The trunk and other branches all work correctly.

**The Question**

As I've mentioned at the start, the work-around was creating another repository. My concern is the current state of our repository and if this might happen again on another project.

Has anyone else experienced this issue with a branch of a project trunk?
If so, I would be greatly interested in how they resolved it.

many thanks in advance, Neil

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772894/updating-from-svn-repository-returns-could-not-read-chunk-size-error)? File-based source control can unfortunately can suffer from these kind of issues, regular backups are a mitigation strategy..

Comment: Yes Stuart I have. I have checked the Apache server and updated the configuration, on the off-change this might of been the cause. However this issue is different, in that the trunk and other branches all work correctly - the problem is just with this branch.

Comment: Are the contents of this branch significantly larger than the other portions of the repository you are able to check out? What version of Subversion are you running (client *and* server)?

Comment: There was a couple of extra images and various source files - no more than 1MB. All the branches are around the same size (1 GB checked out).  With regards the versions of client and server - at present I'm at home - so this is from memory - Server 1.7.84, Clients TortoiseSVN 1.7, Mac iOS 10.9.4 and the SVN client that comes packaged with Ubuntu 12. (Thanks Alroc for answering at the weekend!)